# Embedded Ruby HTML Loops Spit Out Number of Loop

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a partial I have:

```
<%= shift.ones.times do %>
<p>one</p>
<% end %>
```

The final HTML (from the page source) is:

```
<p>one</p>
1
```

Why is this? How can I stop it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This comes up over and over and over again and it is always the same thing, hence the duplicate. To be fair, it can be difficult to find all the duplicates.

Comment: I didn't know that this was the issue I was having so I was not sure what to search for. Should I delete this now that I know?

Answer (score 5):

Just change `<%=` to just `<%`:

```
<% shift.ones.times do %>
  <p>one</p>
<% end %>
```

This happens because `<%=` evaluates the expression and prints the returned value, whereas `<%` just evaluates the expression. And the `times` method returns the number of times the block was processed (`1` time in your example).

Comment: I would explain that using `<%=` actually outputs the returned result of the ruby code, whereas `<%` does not ( `<%` is used for computing without outputting, like looping through an array, setting variables, doing some logic, etc)

Comment: Thanks, stupid mistake on my part.